# Why does JDO Class break Guava MultiMap index?

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo, guava, graniteds

I'm unable to create a multimap index with the JDO Score class below. If I substitute Object[] for Score everything works fine. I thought the issue was that the Score class was not serializable? What am I missing from the Score class?

Score Class:

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType=IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable="true")
@javax.jdo.annotations.Version(strategy=VersionStrategy.VERSION_NUMBER,column="VERSION",
     extensions={@Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="field-name",value="version")})

public class Score implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -8805789255398748271L;

  @PrimaryKey
  @Persistent(primaryKey="true", valueStrategy=IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
  private Key id;

  private Long version;

  @Persistent
  private String uid;

  @Persistent
  private Integer value;
}
```

Multimap index:

```
List<Score> rows = new ArrayList(scores);
Multimap<Key, Score> grouped = Multimaps.index(rows,
  new Function<Score, Key>() {

    public Key apply(Score item) {
      return (Key) item.getObjKey();
    }
});
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: The Multimap index below works with a native Object[]. The code above with the Score class does not. Why doesn't the Score class work in the Multimap index?  

`List<Object []> rows = new ArrayList(obj1, obj2, obj3);  Multimap<Key, Object []> grouped = Multimaps.index(rows,
        new Function<Object [], Key>() {

     public Key apply(Object [] item) {
       return (Key) item.getObjKey();
     }
  });`

Comment: Er, that shouldn't work. Arrays don't have a `getObjKey()` method. You need to explain what exactly you mean by "works" or "doesn't work". Compiler error? Exception at runtime? Unexpected results? Your `Score` class doesn't seem to have a `getObjKey()` method either, so I'm not sure what to think.

Comment: Score class has a method getObjKey, that's not the issue, I omitted it in this post...sorry.
Getting NullPointerException from 
Multimaps.index(rows, new Function<Score, Key>()
List<Score> rows contains data in the debugger, it is populated via…
`PersistenceManager pm = pmf.getPersistenceManager();
pm.getFetchPlan().setDetachmentOptions(FetchPlan.DETACH_UNLOAD_FIELDS);
List<Score> rows = null;
Query q = pm.newQuery(Score.class);
rows = (List<Score>)q.execute();`

Must have a null element in List<Score>? 

If I pass in a an java.lang.Object populated with properties, no exception.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the `NullPointerException`?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:181)
 at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMultimap$Builder.put(ImmutableMultimap.java:148)
 at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.collect.ImmutableListMultimap$Builder.put(ImmutableListMultimap.java:161)
 at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.collect.Multimaps.index(Multimaps.java:1388)

Comment: at org.graniteds.example.gae.controllers.TaskController.groupByMultimap(TaskController.java:271)
 at org.graniteds.example.gae.controllers.TaskController.getleaders(TaskController.java:200)
 at org.graniteds.example.gae.controllers.TaskController$$FastClassByCGLIB$$d7dffaa6.invoke(<generated>)
 at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:628)
 at org.graniteds.example.gae.controllers.TaskController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$15b84e4e.getleaders(<generated>)

Comment: Score is a child of User and User appears to be null in the result set returned from the query.

Comment: By the way, it's better to post additional information like the stack trace by editing the question rather than commenting. It helps make the question understandable and you can format it too.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, if you're going to use Guava you should probably use a real release of Guava rather than code that's repackaged for internal use in app engine.

That said, it looks like (assuming the repackaged code works the same as the current released Guava code) at least one of your `Score` objects' `getObjKey()` method must be returning `null`. `ImmutableMultimap`s don't allow `null` keys or values.